# GateIn: a filter for the login servlet

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, gatein

I need to implement some logic before and after the login servlet invoked by my login.jsp.

So I wrote a filter for the url /login to do that. I need to get the user profile for some operations, so I created this LoginFilter class:

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String username = httpRequest.getParameter("username");
        String password = httpRequest.getParameter("password");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        PortalRequestContext context = PortalRequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (context == null)
            logger.info("PortalRequestContext is NULL");
        else {
            String userId = context.getRemoteUser();

            if (userId == null || userId.equals(""))
                logger.info("Login failed, IP:" + httpRequest.getRemoteAddr());
            else
                logger.info("Login executed, username:" + userId);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that "context" (PortalRequestContext) is always null. What ma I doing wrong? Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GateIn, you can try using

```
org.exoplatform.portal.webui.util.Util.getPortalRequestContext().getRequest()
```

ce

Answer (score 1):

You can develop a Valve and add it into Context file of "portal" webapp (Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/portal.xml).
That's what is done in GateIN for SSO extension for example:
See [ServletAccessValve](https://github.com/gatein/gatein-sso/blob/master/agent/src/main/java/org/gatein/sso/agent/tomcat/ServletAccessValve.java)

```
ServletAccess.setRequestAndResponse(request, response);
```

Then, the Request is accessed in [SSOLoginModule](https://github.com/gatein/gatein-sso/blob/master/agent/src/main/java/org/gatein/sso/agent/login/SSOLoginModule.java) using this:

```
// Tomcat way (Assumed that ServletAccessValve has been configured in context.xml)
  else
  {
     request = ServletAccess.getRequest();
  }
```

For JBoss, it's more simple, you have just to use

```
javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext.getContext(HttpServletRequest.class.getName())
```

Answer (score 0):

At login time, `PortalRequestContext`'s not been created yet, but you can get remote user by calling `HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a GateIN Filter like detailed [here](http://docs.jboss.org/exojcr/1.14.9-GA/developer/en-US/html/chapter-eXoJCRWithGateIn.html#JCRWithGateIn.HowToExtendMyGateInInstance.FAQ).

And you can use statically in this Filter the ConversationState to get the current username:

`ConversationState.getCurrent().getIdentity().getUserId();`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the conversation state object:

```
// Gets the current user id
ConversationState conversationState = ConversationState.getCurrent();

org.exoplatform.services.security.Identity identity = conversationState.getIdentity();
String userId = identity.getUserId();
```